# USB connector ESD protection vs vias vs impedance

Tags: usb, impedance, esd, via

I need to put an ESD protection on USB connection of a 2 layers board.
I decided to use a *specific* component from TI ([TPD4S012](https://www.ti.com/product/TPD4S012)). The application note suggest to use the following layout:

[image: suggested layout]

Since I have some strict size constraints I would like to mount this component on the opposite side of the connector (SMD) and wire it to ID, D+, D- tracks trough vias. Is this a reccomendable placement ?

Could vias modify significantly the impedance of the USB tracks or interfere with signal in some way?

At the moment D+ D- tracks are pretty short (around 7mm) for this reason I also tought to keep the board thickness on standard FR4 (1.6mm) but to match USB tracks impedance I should get to 0.6/0.4mm (or less).

Given the suggested layout I think my idea is correct but I may have forgot something important.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on USB v2, there are no worries as the line frequency is not so critical, as long as you don't go overboard.

In USB v3, it gets more critical.

Comment: USB 2.0 (ATMega32U4)... thnx!

Comment: @weirdgyn So that's only 12 MBit/s Full Speed, not even 480 MBit/s High Speed. That's completely not critical. Do "whatever you like" with the data lines.